# Setup subdirectory redirect to a Laravel project

Tags: apache, laravel, redirect

I have three projects, First one is a static html website and other 2 projects are Laravel projects.

I have an SSL certificate set up for the main website. I want to setup the other Laravel projects as subdirectories of the main URL.

I added an alias to my conf file, but it doesn't work. I get this error: "Too many redirects occurred trying to open “https://example.com/admin/”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page."

Are there any changes that I should add to htaccess file?

Here is my website.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/***********.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/*********.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*********.crt

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public_html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /admin "/var/www/html/admin"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/admin">
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

Alias /admin2  "/var/www/html/admin2"
<Directory "/var/www/html/admin2">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: It would be easier to use real subfolders `admin` and `admin2` with slightly modified `index.php` and having laravel code outside the docroot. There's no need to have code visible from web.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at Vagrant with Laravel Homestead prebuilt box. This will achieve what you want to do by editing the Homestead.yaml file, the /etc/hosts file, and then provisioning the vagrant machine. You will need virtual box installed to work with vagrant. You can SSH into the machine by typing vagrant ssh inside the homestead directory.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead

YouTube Video about Vagrant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyIyyFDgO4o

Youtube Videos about Installing Laravel Homestead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbPGuikTzKk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEaImCreOC7UkK4U5Xv9LdI

Comment: Thanks J! I have a problem here, that the main website is a static html, so I'll not be able to set the Laravel configuration until I convert it to Laravel project. Also the server machine is very small to setup two VM.
I was looking for an easy solution to setup the redirect from Apache server.

Comment: Throw the static website into the a new laravel projects public folder. Follow the directions above. Your problem will be solved. Also delete XAMMP or WAMP or any other apache server and mysql off your machine prior to install of laravel homestead and vagrant. They're going to cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *public* folder as your alias in the apache setup.

Try **"/var/www/html/admin2/public"** and also for the Directory as well.

Something like this:

```
Alias /admin2  "/var/www/html/admin2/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/admin2/public">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Depends on the installation of Laravel, you should have an .htaccess file in the public directory, which might require some additional tweeking.

Also, restart apache once you have made the change.t

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly set 2 things :

1. Your sites's alias in WAMP's alias folder e.g. `C:\wamp\alias` to redirect URL to `public\index.php` in Laravel's folder
2. Rewrite base `.htaccess` in your Laravel's `public` folder so that Apache rewrites on top of a base path.

Assuming that your site's directory is in `C:\wamp\www\site` and your alias is `localhost/alias`

1. Setting alias to point to `public` folder:

```
    Alias /site  "/var/www/site/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/site/public">
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

2. Add `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` in Laravel's `public` folder

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        </IfModule>
    
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase '/site/'
    
        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```